# Check if file is rewritable in shell

Tags: powershell, shell

Assuming i have file in my server  as

1. `-rw-r--r--. dev Jun 28 06:51 test1.log`

I have 3 user which have access to my server , [dev,dev1,dev2]

I understand that we can check if the file is rewritable by me by using below code

```
-w test1.log
```

But i want to check if file is rewritable for other users even i log in to my server as dev instead of dev1

The current approach i am doing is by using below script however this approach will have issue if it suddenly created as dev2 user

```
if [ -w test1.log ]
then "True"
else echo "not rewritable"
fi
```

Dev user will return this as True 
Dev1 User will return this as false

Is ther a way we can check the file type if its `-rw-r--r--` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Invoke-Command` you can pass the command credentials to run fairly easily. You can throw in a loop of credentials to test each user you need. Wrapping it in a Try/Catch allows you to easily see if there are any errors with the process. You can display the errors with a simple `$Error`.

Here is the documentation on the class with its methods. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0

```
Try {
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {[io.file]::OpenWrite(".\test1.log").close()} -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Credential $(Get-Credential)
    return $true
} Catch {
    Write-Warning "not rewritable"
    return $false
}
```